# Mysql db class - trouble connecting

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

So I'm trying to make a mysql database class, and I want to keep my db selection in a seperate method from the constructor. For some reason it the setDb() function doesn't want to work.

```
class mysql
{
    public function __construct($server,$user,$pass)
{
    if(!$this->mysql_connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass))
        print 'Could not connect to MySQL';
}

    public function setDb($dbname)
{
    $this->database = $dbname;
    if(!mysql_select_db($this->database,$this->mysql_connection))
        $this->database = '';
        print 'Could not connect to the MySQL database';
        return false;
    return true;
}

    private $database;
private $mysql_connection;
}
```

Comment: rather than your print and return statements you might want to try die() to ensure that you aren't missing an error message. Also, how are you calling your mysql class?

Comment: die(mysql_error()) should spit out the error details

Comment: Have you considered using/studying existing database access layers and/or abstractions - like e.g. http://docs.php.net/pdo , http://adodb.sourceforge.net ,http://www.doctrine-project.org , ...many, many more - before trying your own?

Answer (score 1):

You could throw an exception in case of a MySQL error, e.g.

```
class DbMySQL
{
  protected $database;
  protected $mysql_connection;

  public function __construct($server,$user,$pass)
  {
    $this->mysql_connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
    if( !$this->mysql_connection ) {
      throw new ErrorException(mysql_error(), mysql_errno());
    }
  }

  public function setDb($dbname)
  {
    if ( !mysql_select_db($dbname, $this->mysql_connection) ) {
      throw new ErrorException(mysql_error($this->mysql_connection), mysql_errno($this->mysql_connection));
    }
    else {
      $this->database = $dbname;
    }
    return $this;
  }
}

$m = new DbMySQL('localhost', '...', '...');
$m->setDB('...');
```

Maybe [ErrorException()](http://docs.php.net/errorexception) is not the best choice, but I hope you get the idea ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any glaring problems.  Are you calling your class like below?

```
$db = new mysql($server, $user, $password);
$db->setDb('YOUR_DATABASE_NAME');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add curly braces after your mysql_select_db line, and before the return true line. Only the first statement under the condition is executed when the condition is met. So the function always returns false.